# Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int Symfony2

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I want to get and save total hours for two time during create action

Yaml

```
    timein:
        type: time
    timeout:
        type: time
        nullable: true
    total:
        type: time
        nullable: true
```

Entity

```
 private $timein;//DateTime
 private $timeout;//DateTime
 private $total;//DateTime

 /**
 * Get total
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getTotal()
{
    return $this->total;
}

/**
 * Set total
 *
 * @param \DateTime $total
 *
 * @return Timerecord
 */
public function setTotal($total)
{
    $this->total = $total;

    return $this;
}

public function getWorkedHoursTimeinTimeout()
{


  if (!empty($this->timein) && !empty($this->timeout)) {
        //if already timed in and timed out, calculate hours from timein to timeout
        $start = $this->timein;
        $end = $this->timeout;
        $start1 = $start;
        $end1 = $end;
        $total_hours = round(($end1-$start1) / 3600);//option1 

    return  $total_hours;



    } /*else {
        $this->total = "";
    }*/

}
```

Now Inside the controller, I want to save the total hours for timeim and timeout like this

```
 $entity->setTotal($entity->getWorkedHoursTimeinTimeout());
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
```

But I got this error

> Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int

$timein, $total and $timeout is actually of time type in Doctrine.yml but it will automatically converted to DateTime when running

```
  php app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

And in Mysql, $timein and $timeout is of time type

Now when I refactor my getWorkedHoursTimeinTimeout()

```
public function getWorkedHoursTimeinTimeout()
{


  if (!empty($this->timein) && !empty($this->timeout)) {
        //if already timed in and timed out, calculate hours from timein to timeout
        $start = $this->timein;
        $end = $this->timeout;
        $start1 = $start;
        $end1 = $end;
        $total_hours = $end1->diff($start1);//option1 

    return  $total_hours;

}
```

This return no error but does not save the actual total hour, instead it will save a value of

```
 00:00:00
```

Now I tried to return and save instead the value of either the $timein or $timeout

```
 if (!empty($this->timein) && !empty($this->timeout)) {
        //if already timed in and timed out, calculate hours from timein to timeout
        $start = $this->timein;
        $end = $this->timeout;
        $start1 = $start;
        $end1 = $end;
        $total_hours = $end1->diff($start1);//option1 

    return  $start;//02:00:04



    } /*else {
```

And it actually save to the total column in Mysql

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

`Total` is `DateTime Object` and you try save `DateInterval Object`. Change type for `Total` in Entity to `dateinterval`

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: This will return when you dump `DateTime Object`: `object(DateTime)#790 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-01-27 02:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } `

And this when `DateInterval Object`: `object(DateInterval)#780 (15) { ["y"]=> int(0) ["m"]=> int(0) ["d"]=> int(0) ["h"]=> int(1) ["i"]=> int(0) ["s"]=> int(0) ["weekday"]=> int(0) ["weekday_behavior"]=> int(0) ["first_last_day_of"]=> int(0) ["invert"]=> int(0) ["days"]=> int(0)`

change `@ORM\Column(type="datetime")` to `@ORM\Column( type="dateinterval")`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but Symfony2 complains of unknown column type of dateinterval

Comment: Which Symfony version do you have?

Comment: I am using the 2.7 version

Comment: I don't think there is an fieldtype of dateinterval as discussed here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping

Comment: You have outdate Doctrine/ORM vendors. You can update it by Composer or use: `$example = new \DateTime($diff->format("%h:%i:%s"));`
`$diff` is Dateinterval Object but `$example` will return today date with change hours, minutes and secounds

Comment: I created field with dateinterval and i hadn't error

Comment: I will try this .I am new to Symfony2 and I have difficulty in figuring it out.BTW, I am using YAML for mapping.Any idea on field type? example integer for id fields

Comment: Do you mean who to create auto_increment field?

Comment: no.What I mean the total field.In your example, its in Annotation format .I am using YAML.

Comment: And how it will be in Yaml?

Comment: Something like total:
                        type: dateinterval//this will actually fail when running doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: maybe use string. You can save values in the appropriate format.

Comment: Or save timein and timeout in datebase than in code you can calculate diff

Comment: That is what I am doing right now.get the value of timein(02:45:00) and timeout(03:50:12) get  the total hours and save to the total column

Comment: If it's only round integer use integer. For example: timein (02:45:00) and timeout(03:50:12) diff will be 1:05:12 convert all to secound than divide by 3600 than round and save result as integer

Comment: Maybe you can show your working code so that I can accept it

Comment: it's in simple php because i don't know when you get timein and timeout `$timein = new DateTime('02:00:00');
$timeout = new DateTime('03:30:20');


$pre_total = $timein->diff($timeout);

$convert = ($pre_total->format('%h')*3600+$pre_total->format('%i')*60+$pre_total->format('%s'))/3600;

$total = round($convert);`

Comment: This is how I get $timeout = $entity->getTimeout();//02:09:00..But   $timeout = new \DateTime($entity->getTimeout()); does not work..DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.I think I am almost there.

Comment: first you save timein timeout in db than save total?

Comment: or make all in same time?

Comment: yes timein and timeout values already save in db.what i want is to get the total hours for this two fields and save it to the total column

Comment: my remaining problem is this  $timeout = new \DateTime($entity->getTimeout()); instead of this $timeout = new \DateTime("03:00:09")

Comment: [check this](http://pastebin.com/FC5eABmm). You problem is that $entity->getTimeout() is already DateTime and you try make DateTime object using DataTime object

Comment: I wil try this tomorrow

Comment: Do you any  Idea for this error? Error: Call to a member function format() on double